# Using swipe gestures to change pages in multi page jquery mobile application does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple pages and try to change between them if a swipe event occurs. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799491/4684797) on SO and tried it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Share QR</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="article1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <h1>Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Article 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="article2">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
      <h1>Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Article 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="article3">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
      <h1>Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Article 3</p>
    </div>
    </div>

        <script>
            $(document).on
            (
                'swipeleft',
                '.ui-page',
                function(event)
                {    
                    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
                    {    
                        var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
                        // swipe using id of next page if exists
                        if (nextpage.length > 0)
                        {
                            $.mobile.changePage
                            (
                                nextpage,
                                {transition: "slide", reverse: false},
                                true,
                                true
                            );
                        }
                        event.handled = true;
                    }
                    return false;         
                }
            );

            $(document).on
            (
                'swiperight', 
                '.ui-page', 
                function(event)
                {     
                    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
                    {      
                            var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
                            if (prevpage.length > 0) 
                            {
                                    $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
                            }
                            event.handled = true;
                    }
                    return false;            
                }
            );

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But i only get this output on my windows phone (windows 10) and on my desktop browser.

[image]